# Same build - diffrent environment (AWS, Docker, SpringBoot, Angular, Nginx)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, environment-variables

I have a WebApp using:

Frontend: Angular 4, Nginx, Docker, AWS(ELB-single Docker)

Backend: SpringBoot, Docker, AWS(ELB-single Docker)

Pretty common case. Now I would like run diffrent instances of this app swiched by an environment variable. Since its always the same build just with other DB/entrypoint configurations. And Iam a bit scary how to implement this straight forward and correct. Also open for sugesstions. I already have diffrent environments in Angular and SpringBoot running. But this with preconfiged build files (with production or qa set) But I would like to avoid the useless rebuilds.

**Question now is:**
Do someone already build something like this and could give me a little example for what the config files need to look like?

> -> Dockerfile -> Dockerrun.aws.json -> ...

Espacially the frontend part is my problem:

> -> Dockerfile -> Dockerrun.aws.json -> nginx.conf.d -> "any Angular config?"

Answer (score 0):

To switch the configuration I would move the configurable parameters out of the code if that isn't the case yet.

For the front-end you can move it to a separate json file or you can use data- attributes in your html page. These can be easily changed in a post-build step, or pre-configured by hand, depending on need.

Comment: Hmm, so you suggest to make a build-job for "qa" or "prod" which is just injecting/zipping a another "configfile" into the build artifact?

Comment: I thought about defining diffrent artifacts to deploy on the next step then. And packing them both at the first build step. Any problem with that?

Comment: ohu.. and do you have link maybe that shows how angular is using asset config files? Didnt see that before

Comment: If angular is already running you can just use https://angular.io/guide/http - otherwise use whatever you can depending on js versions and/or libraries available. And if you don't care about more builds you can of course just create 2 builds instead of 1 build + postprocessing.

Comment: Yes, u r sadly right! It could be so cool to handle websites as application not as passive scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I found an awsome but horrible solution which just shows me again how "aged" current webtechnologies are today.

https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984

This ones using the env variable to "rebuild" angular using the env-vars on each start of the docker container. 
Well its a cool approach. But very sad that its neccessary to achieve that.